# PHP use result field value from mysql query for mail receiver

Tags: php

I need help for this PHP script:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'Username', 'PW');
$sql = "SELECT Driver, Mail FROM mytable";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$emailBody="";
$Subject="test";
$to ="xxx";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $emailBody .= "Driver:   ".$row['Driver']."\n";
}

$to = str_replace('xxx', $row['Mail'], $to);
mail($to, $Subject, $emailBody);
```

I tried many things:

```
mail($to, $Subject, $emailBody);
mail($row['Mail'], $Subject, $emailBody);
```

I cannot set the field value of row['Mail'] as the receiver address.
The field values have been tested with  "mymail@mail.com"   and   'mymail@mail.com'  and   mymail@mail.com  .

The replace function was just another trial.

```
$to =str_replace('xxx',$row['Mail'],$to);
```

Nothing works except hardcoding for test only..

```
mail("mymail@mail.com", $Subject, $emailBody);
```

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly is the issue? Does the mail get sent to a wrong address? Do you get an error when trying to send it?

Comment: The body of your loop is just `{$emailBody .= "Driver:   ".$row['Driver']."\n";}`, everything else executes after the loop is done. And then $row is of course just `false`.

Comment: Why are you using the long-deprecated `mysql_` code library? It was discontinued many years ago and removed entirely in PHP7. No new code should be written using this library. It can leave you vulnerable to SQL injection attacks (due to the lack of parameterised query support) and potentially other unpatched vulnerabilities. Switch to using `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible, and then learn how to write parameterised queries to protect your data from malicious input. See http://bobby-tables.com for a simple explanation of the risks and some sample PHP code to write queries safely.

Comment: Also, if you are running `mysql_` queries successfully, it shows you are running an unsupported version of PHP. You should upgrade your PHP version urgently to continue to receive security updates. https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php

Comment: Anyway, now we add some proper formatting and indentation to your code (which you should always do), you can hopefully the problem becomes clearer - `$row` only exists inside your loop (i.e. inside the `{` and `}`). But your `$to` line exists outside the loop, therefore it cannot access any values from `$row`. It's a simple but obvious logic error. P.S. It's unclear if you're trying to send a separate email for each row in the database, or one big email containing the data from all the rows, and sent to all the addresses at once?

Comment: Since yesterday, I did not need to do something with PHP. Sorry, but I copied the core of the code from internet. That's why it might be outdated.

@ADyson: I cannot see that the $to variable is OUTSIDE the loop. It is prefilled outside but then edited inside with the replace string. There might me a few rows for every php calls which generate a maill for every row. The above code is shortend for better understanding but the only problem I face is the variable setting of the $to value.

Comment: @El_Vanja: no error at all, but not send to receiver. I guess the Mail-address was not set.

Comment: _"I cannot see that the $to variable is OUTSIDE the loop"_....what??? It's clearly after the `}` which indicates the end of the loop. Do you not understand this basic PHP syntax or something? _"It is prefilled outside but then edited inside with the replace string"_ ...no, it really really isn't. Please look at your code more carefully.

Comment: _"I copied the core of the code from internet"_ please don't blindly copy code you don't understand. It can be very risky. At best it's fine, but realistically you can end up including stuff you don't really need for your specific purpose, and at worst you can be using obsolete and/or insecure code. At least do some basic research on it first.

Comment: **Warning:** `mysql_*` extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and has been removed as of PHP 7.0.0. Instead, either the [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) extension should be used. See also the [MySQL API Overview](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

Comment: ADyson: you are right, I DO NOT understand it! For my understanding the loop starts at the while statement and returns to the next row after the mail statement. But obvoiusly I am wrong. So would you be so kind and correct the code in a way that I do understand it. I am used to set some return statements like loop, next whatever to return to the next row. in PHP I cannot see were and how the return works. You used the  { and } only for the $emailBody variable. Is it neccessary to include the mail statement? Sorry, but I am a newbie.

Comment: In general I understood what I was copying. I just have huge problems with the sxntax of PHP.

Comment: "For my understanding the loop starts at the while statement and returns to the next row after the mail statement"...nope. As I said at the beginning of these comments, the start and end of the loop is marked by the brackets `{` and `}`. Don't run before you can walk, if you don't understand the most basic syntax, then take a few moments out to study it before trying to write code which involves it. https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php

Comment: Anyway I have already written a correction - see the answer below.

Comment: "in PHP I cannot see were and how the return works"...sorry I've no idea what you mean by this

Comment: "You used the { and } only for the $emailBody variable"...I didn't do that, you did that. All I did was edit the presentation of your code to make it clearer to see the boundaries of the loop (using standard formatting conventions used by most programmers).

Answer (score -1):

`$row` only exists inside your loop (i.e. inside the `{` and `}`). But your `$to` line exists *outside* the loop, therefore it cannot access any values from `$row`.

If, as you mention in the comments, you wish to generate a separate email for each row of your query results then

a) you need to move the code which sets the recipient and sends the mail *inside* the loop so it can access the row data, and execute once per row

and

b) you need to *not* concatenate the body with data from every row, otherwise every email after the first will contain details from all the previous rows as well as the current one.

This should work better:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'Username', 'PW');
$sql = "SELECT Driver, Mail FROM mytable";
$query = mysql_query($sql);
$Subject="test";

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  $emailBody = "Driver:   ".$row['Driver']."\n";
  mail($row['Mail'], $Subject, $emailBody);
}
```

---

P.S. As I mentioned in the comments, you need to **urgently** replace the obsolete `mysql_` calls with mysqli or PDO, and **urgently** upgrade to a supported version of PHP.  I'd also recommend using a library like `PHPMailer` to handle your email sending - it's easier to work with than `mail()` and is more likely to generate valid emails which won't get accidentally blocked as spam etc. It can also support SMTP where mail() only supports local mailservers via sendmail.

Comment: Now it seems clear to me that the { and } defines the loop. In your correction of my initial posting you just included the $emailbody with the { and } which confused me. Now I understand how  loop statements are bound together. I will instantely as well as using the mysqli. But still I do not know HOW the mail adress should be passed to the function: with quotes, double quotes or without any, just plain like   mymail@mail.com  ?

Comment: `In your correction of my initial posting you just included the $emailbody with the { and }` ...that was me editing your question to make it clearer, not providing a solution or correcting the code. Those are two different processes in StackOverflow!

Comment: `still I do not know HOW the mail adress should be passed to the function`...then read the documentation and look at the many examples available online, both there and in tutorials. Start with the docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php